# calling variables from one method to another

Tags: java

Alright, this is driving me crazy! I have two methods and two classes. I am trying to call a variable from method A to method B.  Method A resides in Class A, however it extends Class B.  Method B is in Class B.  I am using private variables with get/set, but I cannot understand why, when the variable is update in method A it is not transferring over to method B, even though the variable resides in Class B. Here is the code:

```
public class A extends class B {
   public double method A () {
     setSales(userInput.nextDouble());
     double mySales = getSales;
System.out.print("my sales is " +mySales+);
    }
}

public class B {
    private double sales;

    void setSales(double sales) {
    this.sales=sales;
    }

    double getSales() {
    return sales;
    }

   public method B () {
      System.out.print(+sales+);
      //printout equals 0 with user input of any number
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the usage?

Comment: not sure what you mean, usage? basically the sales variable is going into an if statement, but I wasn't getting anything back.  I put a print statement in and found this variable isn't carrying over.  Apologies, fairly new to java

Comment: In class `A` you have `double mySales = getSales;`. Where is `getSales` variable defined and initialized?

Comment: By "usage" we usually mean your `main()` method.

Comment: ok, thanks.  the main method is in another class. I am getting the method  A results back, along with method B, but again, the sales isn't carrying over.

Answer (score 0):

Local Variables Have No Memory

When you exit a method, both the local variables and the parameter variables disappear (although, if you pass an object as a parameter, you usually have access to the object when you exit the method).
That means if you make a call to testRightTriangle() and run the declarations, it creates new boxes and initializes them. When you exit, those local variables disappears.

When you call it a second time, it recreates the local variables, and reinitializes them.

Parameters behave somewhat like this. These variables gets initalized to the arguments.

Only instance variables maintain their value over method calls. That is, if some instance variable has value of 4 for height, and you change it to 10, then the next time you make a method call, it's still 10. It stays 10 until some method call changes the value.

Comment: so what you are saying is, when method A closes, the sales variable doesn't retain it's value in class B, which is why in method B, the sales variable is 0?

Answer (score 0):

```
 double mySales = getSales;
```

Needs to be

```
  double mySales = getSales();
```

since getSales is a method.

also

```
this.sales=sales;
```

needs to be switched if you are trying to use the parameter passed to the method to set the private variable in class B.

Comment: sorry, I have that, just left it off when copying.

Answer (score 0):

Class A is not Class B all they have in common are the methods and attributes.
Because Class A extends Class B doesn't mean that they share the same memory thus the field they each hold are stored at different memory locations.
That's why when you update attribute A in Class A it doesn't not transfer over to Class B.
If you want to be able to modify the attribute in Class B you might want to add a parameter to method A.

Change your method A to be this instead:

```
public double method A (Class B instanceToModify) 
 {
     setSales(userInput.nextDouble());
     instanceToModify.mySales = getSales();
     System.out.print("my sales is " +mySales+);
 }
```

Comment: ok, I am trying this, but it is giving me an error in my main().  I will keep see if I can figure it out and come back.

Comment: Ho sorry I forgot you have mySales as private. Use instanceToModify.setSales(this.getSales()); instead of instanceToModify.mySales = getSales();